# FileNotFoundException in Hibernate search and Lucene

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

We use Hibernate Search in our web application and following are releases which we are using:

```
hibernate-search-3.4.1.Final
hibernate3.6.10.jar
lucene-core-3.4.0.jar
```

Previously we had `lucene-core-3.1` but upgraded a couple of months ago because of another issue. Now I am getting following error very often. I searched the net and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085526/lucene-hibernate-search-lock-exception) and [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-614) and a couple of others but they don't seem to be same as mine. Here is the stack trace:

```
2013-09-29 15:10:43,624 ERROR LogErrorHandler:82 - Exception occurred java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\sql-cluster\data\indexes\mycomp.domain.Item\_1ut.cfs (The system cannot find the file specified)
Primary Failure:
    Entity mycomp.domain.Item  Id 4761556  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\sql-cluster\data\indexes\mycomp.domain.Item\_1ut.cfs (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.openInput(MMapDirectory.java:214)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileReader.<init>(CompoundFileReader.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileReader.<init>(CompoundFileReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getFieldInfos(IndexWriter.java:1222)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getCurrentFieldInfos(IndexWriter.java:1242)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1175)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.Workspace.createNewIndexWriter(Workspace.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.Workspace.getIndexWriter(Workspace.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.PerDPQueueProcessor.run(PerDPQueueProcessor.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-09-29 15:10:43,624 ERROR PerDPQueueProcessor:118 - Unexpected error in Lucene Backend: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.works.AddWorkDelegate.performWork(AddWorkDelegate.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.PerDPQueueProcessor.run(PerDPQueueProcessor.java:106)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-09-29 15:10:43,624 ERROR LogErrorHandler:82 - Exception occurred java.lang.NullPointerException
Primary Failure:
    Entity mycomp.domain.Item  Id 4761556  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.works.AddWorkDelegate.performWork(AddWorkDelegate.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.PerDPQueueProcessor.run(PerDPQueueProcessor.java:106)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your index folder for the specified entity? Also you can check your entity index's by using luke tool. For details https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/contributions.html

Answer (score 1):

Its seems the index file is not present in the location. Please verify the below location.

\sql-cluster\data\indexes\mycomp.domain.Item_1ut.cfs

While  loading the context it looks for the index location.

```
    Most likely your index file is corrupted.
```

or

```
    Your new hibernate lucene library pointing the wrong index path.
```

To Solve this issue you need to recreate the index something like below.

```
FullTextSession session = Search.getFullTextSession(getSessionFactory().openSession());
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

 Transaction transaction  = session.beginTransaction();
 ScrollableResults items = session.createQuery("from Item i ")
                .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

 while(items.next()) {

      Object nextToIndex = items.get(0);
      session.index(nextToIndex);
      session.flushToIndexes();
      session.clear();
}
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think if the index file was corrupted, it would happen always not from time to time. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes of course. However you can check  index by @ashokkuttuva post mentioned tools.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Search 3.4.x requires Lucene version 3.1.x. See also https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-search-parent/3.4.1.Final/hibernate-search-parent-3.4.1.Final.pom.

You'll either need to downgrade Lucene again, or, if you want to use Lucene 3.4.x, you will need to upgrade Hibernate Search as well.

Comment: @Hardy - Thanks for the edit!  Don't know how many times I looked back at the listed versions, and still read it as Lucene 4.0 each time.